# How to reference a file in the data directory of a Firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm working on a Firefox extension and I need to inject a JavaScript into a page from a content script. In my Chrome extension I have done the following:

```
this.initializeJplayerSupport = function() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.setAttribute('type', 'application/javascript');
  script.setAttribute('src', chrome.extension.getURL('js/custom-jplayer.js'));
  document.head.appendChild(script);
}
```

The file is in my data directory. How can I reference a js file in a firefox extension content script (where I have used `chrome.extension.getURL()` for Chrome)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're in main.js in your SDK-based add-on, you require and use the 'data' helper from the 'self' object:

```
var data = require('self').data;

console.log(data.url('somefile.js')); // prints the resource uri to the file.
```

For more info:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/self#data

Once you get this resource uri, you can then supply it to a content script using self.postMessage or self.port.emit:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts

Comment: That's in the main script right and not in a contentscript? or am I wrong?

Comment: That's in the main script, 'main.js', yes.

Comment: "How can I reference a js file in a firefox plugin **contentscript**". Is it possible or am I looking at it the wrong way?

Comment: added more to the answer. sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Thanks for your help so far will check it out tonight when I get home.

Comment: sorry., i downvoted by mistake., answer is useful. :(

Comment: Thank you. But how can I reference files contained in the plug-in data/ directory from the content script, and not from the main extension script?

Comment: Using relative paths eg from ./data/index.html, to reference ./data/css/style.css you would just do ./css/style.css

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that starting in Firefox 38, `cfx` has been replaced with `jpm`.

Which might be why this line wasn't working for me:

```
var data = require('self').data;
```

I simply had to rewrite it a bit:

```
var data = require('sdk/self').data;
```