# Relative image url in content script in Firefox Add-On SDK

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm currently developing a Firefox extension using Add-On SDK and bumped into a real problem. Basically my extension just injects a content script into a webpage like this:

**main.js**

```
var pageMod = require("page-mod");
var self = require("self");

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "http://mail.google.com/mail/*",
  contentScriptFile: [self.data.url("jquery.js"),
                      self.data.url("start.js")],
  attachTo : ["top"]
});
```

**start.js**

```
$('body').append('<div>1</div><img src="insertnote.png" /><div>2</div>');
```

Both `start.js` and `insertnote.png` are located in the data folder.
Everything works except for the image. I just could't find how to get the real url for the image tag. Relative url doesn't seem to be working. :(

Is that even possible to include the addon's inner images inside content scripts or should I just use absolute urls to my webserver?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reference a file in the data directory of a Firefox extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551467/how-to-reference-a-file-in-the-data-directory-of-a-firefox-extension)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should work

**main.js**

```
var pngurl = self.data.url("insertnote.png");

//inside PageMod constructor
onAttach: function(worker) {
  worker.port.emit("imageurl",pngurl);
}
```

**start.js**

```
self.port.on("imageurl", function(imgurl){
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = imgurl;
  document.body.appendChild(img);
});
```

Naturally it would be more efficient to pass just one object containing every asset's url.

Comment: This seems like an option though quite painful. But thanks anyway I accept this answer

Comment: contentScriptOptions can also get this value to where you need it. See answer below.

Answer (score 13):

You can use "contentScriptOptions" to pass the values into the content scripts.

main.js

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
var self = require("sdk/self");
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "http://mail.google.com/mail/*",
  contentScriptFile: [self.data.url("jquery.js"),
                      self.data.url("start.js")],
  attachTo : ["top"],
  contentScriptOptions: {
    pngUrl: self.data.url("insertnote.png")
  }
});
```

start.js

```
$('body').append('<div>1</div><img src="' + self.options.pngUrl + '" /><div>2</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that relative URLs are interpreted relative to the document, which in this case is the page, since you're putting the  directly into the page, as a string.

In general, pages *can* link to images in an add-on if the add-on explicitly says so; they have to use the appropriate chrome:// URI to do that.

Comment: Can you give an example how to use chrome:// URI in my case?

Comment: Yes, please give an example. I tried to add `contentaccessible=yes` to a path but it doesen't seem to work: [How do I make an image accessible that resides inside a Firefox SDK Addon?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23804391)

Comment: @BorisZbarsky: Yes, please give an example. I tried to add `contentaccessible=yes` to a path but it doesen't seem to work: [How do I make an image accessible that resides inside a Firefox SDK Addon?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23804391)

Comment: The question is about Firefox extensions, why do you answer about Chrome?

Comment: @alihaghighatkhah Firefox uses chrome:// URIs internally to reference parts of the browser UI (also known as "the chrome"), and did for many years before the browser named Chrome appeared and attempted to appropriate a generic term for part of the UI as a brand name.

Comment: @BorisZbarsky thanks. of course I used the 'contentScriptOptions' as Sean Colombo answers, and the path to local file was like this: src="resource://jid1-ogfxvudba4qina-at-jetpack/example-extension/data/js/example-file.js"