# How do I check if firebug is installed with javascript?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

Here it is described how to check if Firebug is installed by checking if an image of firebug exists: http://webdevwonders.com/detecting-firefox-add-ons/

But it seems to be a bit outdated, cause the images he uses there don't exist anymore in firebug.

the firebug `chrome.manifest` looks like:

```
content firebug content/firebug/ contentaccessible=yes
...
```

but in the whole addon I only find one png now, and that is placed in the rootfolder of the addon. But some other content is accessible, for example: `chrome://firebug/content/trace.js`

Ho

So, in gerneral:

### How do I make an image accessible that resides inside a Firefox SDK Addon?

I program an Addon and I want to make an image `ok.png` available to all javascripts in Firefox.

I added the image in the data folder and added a `chrome.manifest`

```
content response-timeout-24-hours data/
content response-timeout-24-hours data/ contentaccessible=yes
```

But no way to call it via a URL like

```
chrome://response-timeout-24-hours/data/ok.png
```

How do the paths belong together? which is relative to which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a Bug report [here.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1014499)

So if you want to make your add-on detectable you need another approach:

> you can use a PageMod to attach a content script that would wait for a
>   message from your web-app and "respond" by sending another message
>   back to your app. you would know that if you don't receive the
>   response, your addon is not installed. check out the documentation for
>   more details:
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod

I used this to make [my add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/fix-for-zoomed-default-font) detectable.